future cannot be sent between threads safely in Rust
I am using Rocket + Capnproto where I receive a request from a Web API(Rocket) and have to send it to another server via RPC (Capnproto)
here my main Rocket setup
#[rocket::main]
async fn main() {   
    rocket::build()
    .mount("/API",routes![invoke])    
    .launch()
    .await.ok();
}

Here my route method
#[post("/API", data = "<request>")]
async fn invoke(request: api_request::APIRequest<'_>)Result<Json<api_response::ApiResponse>, Json<api_response::ApiResponseError>>{

let result = capnp_rpc::client::run_client(String::from("Hello World")).await;
}

And here my Capnproto code, this is pretty much the hello world example they have, this works fine separately but once I put it on my Rocket projects fails. As you can see all is wrap in Tokio library.
pub async fn run_client( message: String ) ->Result<String, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let server_addr : String = "127.0.0.1:4000".to_string();
    let addr = server_addr
        .to_socket_addrs().unwrap()
        .next()
        .expect("could not parse address");       
        
        rocket::tokio::task::LocalSet::new()
        .run_until( async move {
            let stream = rocket::tokio::net::TcpStream::connect(&addr).await?;
            stream.set_nodelay(true).unwrap();
            let (reader, writer) =
                tokio_util::compat::TokioAsyncReadCompatExt::compat(stream).split();
            let rpc_network = Box::new(twoparty::VatNetwork::new(
                futures::io::BufReader::new(reader),
                futures::io::BufWriter::new(writer),
                rpc_twoparty_capnp::Side::Client,
                Default::default(),
            ));
            let mut rpc_system = RpcSystem::new(rpc_network, None);
            let hello_world: hello_world::Client =
                rpc_system.bootstrap(rpc_twoparty_capnp::Side::Server);

            rocket::tokio::task::spawn_local(rpc_system);           
           
            let mut request = hello_world.say_hello_request();
            request.get().init_request().set_name(&message[..]);

            let reply = request.send().promise.await?;           
            let reply_message  = reply.get()?.get_reply()?.get_message()?.to_str()?;
            println!("received: {}", reply_message);
            Ok(reply_message.to_string())
        }).await

}

here the full error I am getting
error: future cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> src/main.rs:92:1
    |
92  | #[post("/API", data = "<request>")]
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ future created by async block is not `Send`
    |
    = help: within `{async block@src/main.rs:92:1: 92:36}`, the trait `std::marker::Send` is not implemented for `Rc<tokio::task::local::Context>`, which is required by `{async block@src/main.rs:92:1: 92:36}: std::marker::Send`
note: future is not `Send` as this value is used across an await
   --> src\infrastructure\capnp_rpc\client.rs:284:16
    |
257 |          rocket::tokio::task::LocalSet::new()
    |          ------------------------------------ has type `LocalSet` which is not `Send`
...
284 |             }).await.unwrap()
    |                ^^^^^ await occurs here, with `rocket::tokio::task::LocalSet::new()` maybe used later
    = note: required for the cast from `Pin<Box<{async block@src/main.rs:92:1: 92:36}>>` to `Pin<Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = Outcome<rocket::Response<'_>, Status, (rocket::Data<'_>, Status)>> + std::marker::Send>>`
    = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `post` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error: future cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> src/main.rs:92:1
    |
92  | #[post("/API", data = "<request>")]
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ future created by async block is not `Send`
    |
    = help: within `{async block@src/main.rs:92:1: 92:36}`, the trait `std::marker::Send` is not implemented for `*const ()`, which is required by `{async block@src/main.rs:92:1: 92:36}: std::marker::Send`
note: future is not `Send` as this value is used across an await
   --> src\infrastructure\capnp_rpc\client.rs:284:16
    |
257 |          rocket::tokio::task::LocalSet::new()
    |          ------------------------------------ has type `LocalSet` which is not `Send`
...
284 |             }).await.unwrap()
    |                ^^^^^ await occurs here, with `rocket::tokio::task::LocalSet::new()` maybe used later
    = note: required for the cast from `Pin<Box<{async block@src/main.rs:92:1: 92:36}>>` to `Pin<Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = Outcome<rocket::Response<'_>, Status, (rocket::Data<'_>, Status)>> + std::marker::Send>>`
    = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `post` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error: future cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> src/main.rs:92:1
    |
92  | #[post("/API", data = "<request>")]
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ future created by async block is not `Send`
    |
    = help: the trait `std::marker::Send` is not implemented for `dyn StdError`, which is required by `{async block@src/main.rs:92:1: 92:36}: std::marker::Send`
note: future is not `Send` as it awaits another future which is not `Send`
   --> src\infrastructure\capnp_rpc\client.rs:257:10
    |
257 | /          rocket::tokio::task::LocalSet::new()
258 | |             .spawn_local( async move {
259 | |                 let stream = rocket::tokio::net::TcpStream::connect(&addr).await?;
260 | |                 stream.set_nodelay(true).unwrap();
...   |
283 | |                 Ok(reply_message.to_string())
284 | |             }).await.unwrap()
    | |______________^ await occurs here on type `tokio::task::JoinHandle<Result<std::string::String, Box<dyn StdError>>>`, which is not `Send`
    = note: required for the cast from `Pin<Box<{async block@src/main.rs:92:1: 92:36}>>` to `Pin<Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = Outcome<rocket::Response<'_>, Status, (rocket::Data<'_>, Status)>> + std::marker::Send>>`
    = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `post` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

From what I was able to investigate, Rocket has its own threat-worker and seem that this code is trying to start another threat-worker. I have tried few things from another questions trying to use Mutex, but could not make it work.
Not sure how to wrap this code so it can work under Rocket main threat-worker.

Why are you using a LocalSet? What happens if you just remove it and put the code straight in the method?

that is how all examples of capnproto are, if I remove that, this lines does not work
rocket::tokio::task::spawn_local(rpc_system);

What if you remove the LocalSet, but replace the rocket::tokio::task::spawn_local(rpc_system); with rocket::tokio::task::LocalSet::new().spawn_local(rpc_system);?

This question is similar to: Rust "future cannot be sent between threads safely". If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Rob I fail to see how the answers in either Q&A there would help OP here

@ChayimFriedman I am getting the same error, thanks

@Rob unfortunately my Rust level is not that advance, I have seen both question and I am not sure how I could implement the solution here, thanks

See https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/struct.LocalSet.html#use-inside-tokiospawn

What if you keep the LocalSet, but replace the run_until with spawn_local?

@ChayimFriedman if I do that I get another error, mismatch types.

Can you post that error (in the question)?

@ChayimFriedman hi, I have added the cargo check errors above after making the changes "Keep LocalSet but replace run_until with spawn_local" thanks

After getting help from few coworkers and I was able to make this work, here the code as I want to share the solution, still is little hard for me to understand, but I think the important part is to create a new threat from the main threat and then use the capnproto code.
use capnp_rpc::{rpc_twoparty_capnp, twoparty, RpcSystem};
use rocket::futures::AsyncReadExt;
use rocket::*;
use std::net::ToSocketAddrs;
use tokio::runtime::Builder;
use tokio::sync::oneshot;
use tokio::sync::oneshot::error::RecvError;
use tokio::task::LocalSet;

#[post("/API", data = "<request>")]
async fn invoke(request: &str) {
    println!("req {}", request);
    let mut client = RpcClient::new(String::from("Hello World"));
    let response = client.get_response().await;
}

pub struct RpcClient {
    receiver: oneshot::Receiver<String>,
}

impl RpcClient {
    fn new(message: String) -> Self {
        let (sender, receiver) = oneshot::channel();
        let rt = Builder::new_current_thread().enable_all().build().unwrap();
        let server_addr: String = "127.0.0.1:4000".to_string();
        let addr = server_addr
            .to_socket_addrs()
            .unwrap()
            .next()
            .expect("could not parse address");
        std::thread::spawn(move || {
            let local = LocalSet::new();
            local.spawn_local(async move {
                let stream = rocket::tokio::net::TcpStream::connect(&addr).await?;
                stream.set_nodelay(true).unwrap();
                let (reader, writer) =
                    tokio_util::compat::TokioAsyncReadCompatExt::compat(stream).split();
                let rpc_network = Box::new(twoparty::VatNetwork::new(
                    futures::io::BufReader::new(reader),
                    futures::io::BufWriter::new(writer),
                    rpc_twoparty_capnp::Side::Client,
                    Default::default(),
                ));
                let mut rpc_system = RpcSystem::new(rpc_network, None);
                let hello_world: hello_world::Client =
                    rpc_system.bootstrap(rpc_twoparty_capnp::Side::Server);
                
                rocket::tokio::task::spawn_local(rpc_system);
                
                let mut request = hello_world.say_hello_request();
                request.get().init_request().set_name(&message[..]);
                
                let reply = request.send().promise.await?;
                let reply_message = reply.get()?.get_reply()?.get_message()?.to_str()?;
                println!("received: {}", reply_message);
                // send the message to the receiver
                sender.send(reply_message.to_string()).unwrap();
                Ok::<String, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>(reply_message.to_string())
            });
            rt.block_on(local);
        });
        Self { receiver }
    }

    async fn get_response(mut self) -> Result<String, String> {
        match self.receiver.await {
            Ok(response) => Ok(response),
            Err(error) => Err(error.to_string()),
        }
    }
}
#[rocket::main]
async fn main() {
    rocket::build()
        .mount("/API", routes![invoke])
        .launch()
        .await
        .ok();
}

Thanks

It is fundamentally impossible to run a local task (task that must run on the same thread) inside a non-local task, since the owner task may move between threads and move the local task with it.
Since all rocket requests are non-local tasks, that mean they cannot run capnproto's code. The only remaining choice is the main task. It will need to manage an event loop, spawning capnproto tasks while also running the app. The other tasks will communicate with it via channels.
Here's the skeleton:
use std::future::Future;
use std::pin::Pin;

use tokio::sync::mpsc;
use tokio::sync::oneshot;
use tokio::task::LocalSet;

type Job = Box<dyn FnOnce() -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = ()>>>>;

async fn send_job<Fut>(tx: &mpsc::Sender<Job>, job: impl FnOnce() -> Fut + 'static) -> Fut::Output
where
    Fut: Future + 'static,
    Fut::Output: 'static,
{
    let (result_tx, result_rx) = oneshot::channel();
    tx.send(Box::new(move || {
        let fut = job();
        Box::pin(async move {
            let result = fut.await;
            result_tx.send(result).unwrap_or_else(|_| panic!());
        })
    }))
    .await
    .unwrap();
    result_rx.await.unwrap()
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let local_set = LocalSet::new();
    local_set
        .run_until(async {
            // Choose a reasonable number here. If we are at the limit,
            // that means requests are coming too fast and we need to throttle them.
            let (tx, mut rx) = mpsc::channel::<Job>(100);

            local_set.spawn_local(async move {
                loop {
                    let job = rx.recv().await.expect("no sender?");
                    tokio::task::spawn_local(job());
                }
            });

            main_work(tx).await;
        })
        .await;
}

async fn main_work(tx: mpsc::Sender<Job>) {}

Inside main_work() you launch rocket. tx needs to be available to all requests, use State for that.
Then, when some request need to run capnproto task, it will call:
let result = send_job(&tx, move || async move {
    // Code here.
})
.await;

This design limits scalability by only using one core for capnproto tasks, but this comes directly from the limitations of the capnp-rpc crate.
